# How to show multiple activity from broadcast receiver even if the phone is in home screen?

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

Here is my code in `Broadcast Receiver`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    UODataBase uODataBase = new UODataBase(context);
    ArrayList<UOMainListViewItem> tempArrayList = uODataBase
            .getAllReminder(new ArrayList<UOMainListViewItem>());
    uODataBase.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < tempArrayList.size(); i++) {
        if (DateManager.isAValidAlarm(context, tempArrayList.get(i))) {
            Intent alarmActivityIntent = new Intent(context,
                    AlarmPopAtivity.class);
            alarmActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(alarmActivityIntent);
        }
    }
    registerNextTimeToStartService(context);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, opening multiple instance of same activity when android notify the `Broadcast Receiver`. What I'm expecting is get display all the activity one by one when i finish the current showing activity.
This code working perfectly for me if the app is open. I can see all the opened activities one by one.
In case if the app is not opened (that means currently in home screen) and `Broadcast Receiver` got notification from android to show the activities, then instead of showing all the activities one by one it shows only the first activity.

My question: How to show multiple activity from `Broadcast Receiver` even if the phone is in home screen?

Comment: Post your manifest entry for `AlarmPopActivity`

Comment: ` <activity
            android:name="com.KBSK.uo.ui.AlarmPopAtivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        </activity>`